# Why won't $http set a default header?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$http.post('http://localhost:7001/v1/sessions', {
  data: {
    username: $scope.user.username,
    password: $scope.user.password,
    type: 'sessions'
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
  if(response.data.data.token) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = response.data.data.token;
    $state.go('app.dashboard');
  } else {
    $scope.authError = response;
  }
}, function(x) {
  $scope.authError = 'Server Error';
});
```

I can confirm that the `if` condition gets called and a `response.data.data.token` is present.

It goes to the `app.dashboard` state but is intercepted by my `ui-router`:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/app',
  templateUrl: 'tpl/app.html',
  resolve: {
    current_user: ['$http', function($http) {
      return $http.get('http://localhost:7001/v1/users/4/entities');
    }]
  }
})
```

That call, however, does not have anything set in the header. I thought that `$http.defaults` would set a default value in the header. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `$http` context inside controller is like local variable in controller and on making changes in it will not affect globally

Comment: How can I change it so it is affected globally?

Comment: To be honest, it's easier and more readable to wrap `$http` in a custom service, e.g. `request` and then set the variable on it.

Comment: @Sulthan I did exactly what you said, And this would be the better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the default headers in the `config` method and not in your `service`.

Example:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
}]);
```

Only in `config` you can configure the `httpProvider`. If you try to do that inside your service, it won't affect the `$httpProvider` service at all.

EDIT:

You must make use Interceptors in this scenario.

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests.

**[Refer Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)** Interceptor section

Just some sample code:

```
app.service('APIInterceptor', function($rootScope, UserService) {
    var service = this;

    service.request = function(config) { 
       // check if the token is available. Once the token is available get it here from the UserService.
        var access_token = UserService.getToken() || "unauthorized";
        if (access_token) {
            config.headers.authorization = access_token;
        }
        return config;
    };

    service.responseError = function(response) {
        return response;
    };
})
```

In your `config`

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
```

Comment: But I only get the token that I want to set in the header as a response in a controller

Comment: Use interceptor in that case

Answer (score 1):

I would prefered you to one service to use sharable data.

**Code**

```
app.service(dataService, function(){
   this.data = {}
   this.getData = function(){
      return data;
   };

   this.setTokenData = function(token){
      data.token = token;
   }
});
```

Now your code would be while setting token you could use `dataService`

```
  if(response.data.data.token) {
    dataService.setTokenData(response.data.data.token);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = dataService.data.token; //dataService.getData().token;
    $state.go('app.dashboard');
  } else {
    $scope.authError = response;
  }
```

Then from service resolve you could use

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/app',
  templateUrl: 'tpl/app.html',
  resolve: {
    current_user: ['$http', 'dataService', function($http, dataService) {
      $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = dataService.getData().token;
      return $http.get('http://localhost:7001/v1/users/4/entities');
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: I guess interceptors are a better approach for this scenario

Comment: @mohamedrias interceptor is also good idea, but he can do share data by using thing singleton service..